# query join with sum and count mysql

Tags: mysql

i have a sample data like this :

trancation-A

```
=========================
    date        price
=========================
2014-08-16     50000
2014-08-17     60000
2014-08-16     60000
```

trancation-B

```
=========================
    date        price
=========================
2014-08-16     75000
2014-08-17     90000
2014-08-18     70000
```

when parameter date='2014-08-16'

and i want this result like this :

```
=================================
totalA   priceA   totalB  priceB
=================================
2 Unit   110000   1 Unit  75000
```

i run my query :

```
select count(A.price)as totalA, sum(A.price)as priceA, 
count(B.price)as totalB,      sum(B.price)as priceB
from t_penjualan as A join t_pembelian as B
where A.tgl_transaksi = '2014-08-16' and B.tgl_transaksi = '2014-08-16'
```

still wrong...
please help me....

Comment: Issues of data display are best resolved in application-level code. More serious is the (apparent) absence of a PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 1):

Do the aggregation *before* the `join`:

```
select totalA, priceA, totalB, priceB
from (select count(A.price)as totalA, sum(A.price)as priceA
      from t_penjualan A
      where A.tgl_transaksi = '2014-08-16'
     ) A cross join
     (select count(B.price)as totalB, sum(B.price)as priceB
      from t_pembelian as B
      where B.tgl_transaksi = '2014-08-16'
     ) B;
```